# node.js with nginx, how to remove direct ip:port access

Tags: node.js, nginx, port

I inherited a node.js project and I am very new to the platform/language.

The application I inherited is in development so it is a work in progress. In its current state it runs off port 7576 so you access it this way: server_ip:7576

I've been tasked with putting this "prototype" on a live server so my boss can show it to investors etc. But I have to password protect it.

So what I did is I got it running on the live server. And then I made it use a nginx vhost like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;

    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  /usr/ssl/htpasswd;

        access_log   /etc/nginx/logs/access/wip.mydomain.com.access.log;
        error_log  /etc/nginx/logs/error/wip.mydomain.com.error.log;
        server_name  wip.mydomain.com;

        location / { 
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7576;
            root         /var/app;
            expires 30d; 
            #uncomment this is you want to name an index file: 
            #index index.php index.html;
            access_log off; 
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
            root         /var/app/public;
        }
}
```

`

This got the job done, I can now access my app by going to wip.mydomain.com

And I can easily password protect it via nginx.

**My problem is the app is still accessible via the ip:port and I don't know how to prevent that.**

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It depends: if nginx is on the same box local to the node server, you can change node to only listen on localhost/127.0.0.1.  If they are on separate servers, you need to solve this at the network layer (e.g. firewall etc.).  (The firewall method would work in the first situation as well, FYI.)

Comment: nginx is on the same box local to the node server.

And my node application already is listening to localhost, on port 7576.

Did you mean that I should make it listen to port 80? Sorry if I misunderstand

Comment: If it's reachable from outside the box, then it's listening on 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces).  You need to change where the listener is stood up to explicitly only listen on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: hmm... so weird. I am pretty certain it isn't listening to 0.0.0.0, it's listening to localhost/127.0.0.1 already I swear.

Anyway I asked another guy who knows a lot and he suggested I add some iptable rules. I added:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7576 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7576 -j DROP

And that did the trick

Comment: If that 2nd rule is "working" then it means it's listening on more than just 127.0.0.1.  What does `netstat -anp` show for your process?

Comment: Did you do `.listen(…, "127.0.0.1");`, you swear?

Answer (score 9):

In your node javascript code, you need to explicitly bind to the loopback IP:

```
server.listen(7576, '127.0.0.1');
```

(You are looking for a call to `.listen(<port>)` to fix. The variable may be called `app` or something else though).

Any IP address starting with `127.` is a loopback address that can only be accessed within a single machine (doesn't actually use the network).