# How to restrict direct access to a node.js server

Tags: node.js, apache, security, reverse-proxy

I have an apache web server where most of my content is hosted, and then I have a node.js server I'm using for various tasks as well.  I want users to be able to get information from my node.js server only through reverse proxy from my apache server.  I understand how to set up a reverse proxy using mod_proxy on the apache side, but how can I restrict access to the node server except through an apache virtual host?  One option I'm sure would work is to host my node server on a separate box and block any ip address except the apache server.  Is there a way though that I could have them both running on the same machine and configure node to reject requests except from the apache server?

Comment: Make your node listen to 127.0.0.1 and it will not be accessible from outside of your box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js with nginx, how to remove direct ip:port access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030178/node-js-with-nginx-how-to-remove-direct-ipport-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the running on the same box. In the Node server have something like the following:

```
if(req.socket.remoteAddress !== '127.0.0.1'){
  res.writeHead(403, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  res.write('403 Access Denied');
  res.end();
} else { 
  // allow access
  doSomething(); 
}
```

Of course, that allows other processes on the same box to connect to the Node server.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using iptables, allowing incoming connections to port 80 for the webserver. Access to port 3000 from the webserver is allowed because it's coming from the same host.

Here's an example rule file:

```
*filter

# Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Accepts all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allows all outbound traffic
# You could modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

# Allows connections for HTTP
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Allows SSH connections 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Now you should read up on iptables rules and consider whether ssh access 
# for everyone is really desired. Most likely you will only allow access from certain IPs.

# Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# log iptables denied calls (access via 'dmesg' command)
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy:
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

Put this file on your server (e.g. /etc/iptables.up.rules), and run the iptables command to update your iptables rules.

`iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules`